# Does something wrong with Widget&& var1 = someWidget;?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference, universal

recently, i began to learing something about universal reference https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers and it says that `Widget&& var1 = someWidget; //here, "&&" means rvalue reference`. i know that "&&" can be universal reference or rvalue reference,but i thought `somewidget` must be a lvalue, and there is no deduce here, so `Widget&&` && must be rvalue reference, and here is the question. can rvalue reference accept a lvalue, i have learnt that lvalue reference can accept lvalue, and const lvalue reference can accept rvalue, but rvalue reference can only accept rvalue, so is there something wrong with this statement ? or something i miss

Comment: *"can rvalue reference accept a lvalue"*. No. `someWidget` is just a placeholder. Better example might be with `= getSomeWidget()` where that function/placeholder might return correct type.

Comment: so `someWidget` is not a name of some already existing Widget variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that blog post to be confusing. I'd recommend reading a good chapter in a book or the standard itself instead of that post. Part of the problem is that the blog post is 10 years old, so people were still thinking about the new features and how to teach them. I don't think that code even compiles though. I tested `int a = 5; int &&b = a;` and got a compile-time error as expected. I think he meant something like `widget{}` by `someWidget`. `int &&j = int{5};` compiles fine.

However, if you have a template function like `void f(T &&t)`, it can turn into an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference, depending on what is passed to it. The main point of that is to implement perfect forwarding. The old way to do that was to innumerate all possible combinations of arguments, which is exponential in the number of arguments taken. Now, you can write one function that can call other functions with as much efficiency as possible, using the fact something is an rvalue if it is one. Consider the following example:

```
struct W
{
   W(int &, int &) {}
};

struct X
{
   X(int const &, int &) {}
};

struct Y
{
   Y(int &, int const &) {}
};

struct Z
{
   Z(int const &, int const &) {}
};

template <typename T, typename A1, typename A2>
T* factory(A1 &&a1, A2 &&a2)
{
   return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));
}

int main()
{
   int a = 4;
   int b = 5;
   W *pw = factory<W>(a, b);
   X *px = factory<X>(2, b);
   Y *py = factory<Y>(a, 2);
   Z *pz = factory<Z>(2, 2);

   delete pw;
   delete px;
   delete py;
   delete pz;
}
```